# CIR process characteristic function

Tags: stochastic-processes, characteristic-functions

what is the characteristic function of a CIR process given by
$dv_t = \kappa (\theta - v_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t}dW_t$
Unfortunately, I could not find the answer in the literature.
I know it is in the class of affine diffusion processes, but how can we find the characteristic function?

Comment: Since you know it is an affine diffusion, you should be able to solve it (CFs of typical affine diffusions have, in general, closed forms). However, the answer is even more straightforward. Since the distribution is known in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model#Distribution) and the characteristic function is also known in [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution), you just have to plug in the values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not solve the following ODEs
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} - \psi \kappa + \frac{1}{2} \psi^2 \sigma^2 = 0\\
-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \psi \kappa \theta = 0.
\end{align*}
with initial conditions $\phi(0,u)$ and $\phi(0,u)=u$
maybe you can help me with the Riccati equation?

Comment: I posted an answer about the ODEs, which I think is what you needed for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODEs you posted can be written as following (I will use my notation, which is more common in the finance literature):
$$\frac{d}{dt}[C(i\omega,t)]=\theta \mu D(i\omega,t)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}[D(i\omega,t)]=-\theta D(i\omega,t)+\frac{1}{2}\eta^2D(i\omega,t)^2$$
with initial conditions $D(i\omega,0)=i\omega$ and $C(i\omega,0)=0$. We solve $y:=D(i\omega,t)$ first. Divide by $y^2$ and change to the variable $u=1/y$. You get
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\theta u -\frac{1}{2}\eta^2$$
This is a common first order ODE with solution
$$u=u_0e^{\theta t}-\frac{\eta^2}{2\theta}(e^{\theta t}-1)$$
By changing back to $D(i\omega,t)$ (take into account the initial value) you get
$$D(i\omega,t)=\frac{i\omega e^{-\theta t}}{1-\frac{i\omega}{2\theta}\eta^2(1-e^{-\theta t})}$$
By integration in time (from $0$ to $t$) you find the solution to the other ODE
$$C(i\omega, t)=-\frac{2\theta \mu}{\eta^2}\ln\bigg(1-\frac{i\omega}{2\theta}\eta^2(1-e^{-\theta t})\bigg)$$
Since
$$\phi(i\omega,t)=\exp\{C(i\omega, t)+D(i\omega,t)v_0\}$$
you get
$$\phi(i\omega,t)=\bigg(1-\frac{i\omega}{2\theta}\eta^2(1-e^{-\theta t})\bigg)^{-\frac{2\theta \mu}{\eta^2}}\exp\bigg\{\frac{i\omega v_0e^{-\theta t}}{1-\frac{i\omega}{2\theta}\eta^2(1-e^{-\theta t})}\bigg\}$$

Comment: Can you please help me how you get
$$u=u_0e^{\theta t}-\frac{\eta^2}{2\theta}(e^{\theta t}-1)$$?

Comment: $$\frac{du}{dt}e^{-\theta t}-\theta u e^{-\theta t}=-\frac{1}{2}\eta^2e^{-\theta t}$$
$$\frac{du}{dt}(ue^{-\theta t})=-\frac{1}{2}\eta^2e^{-\theta t}$$
Integrate:
$$ue^{-\theta t}-u_0=-\frac{1}{2\theta}\eta^2(1-e^{-\theta t})$$
multiply by $e^{\theta t}$
$$u=u_0e^{\theta t}-\frac{1}{2\theta}\eta^2(e^{\theta t}-1)$$

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if you like it @vandenberg

Comment: *$\frac{d}{dt}(ue^{-\theta t})$ in the second line of the comment

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote (I'm new here) but I will as soon as I can!
Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Comment: You're welcome @vandenberg

Comment: @vandenberg: I just upvoted your question so that you can have 10 more points.